# Why expanding search criteria (time) is actually filtering events in Google Calendar?

Tags: google-calendar-api

First, I am searching my own calendar using:

```
DateTime min = new DateTime(System.currentTimeMillis() - 3600000);
DateTime max = new DateTime(System.currentTimeMillis() + 400000000);

calendarService.events().list("primary").setTimeMin(min).setTimeMax(max).setSingleEvents(false).setShowDeleted(false).execute()
```

And I am getting these two events:

```
Event ID: ttnt08g1300qmc9m92ia2s8a3g_20170517T101500Z
Summary: null
Status: cancelled
Event Start/End: null null
Recurrence: null
RecurringEventId: ttnt08g1300qmc9m92ia2s8a3g

Event ID: cq61agdr4sbdnfj7rfbpbk2pro 
Summary: Google Calendar API test event 
Status: confirmed 
Event Start/End: {"dateTime":"2017-05-17T15:24:53.000+02:00","timeZone":"Europe/Berlin"} {"dateTime":"2017-05-17T16:24:53.000+02:00","timeZone":"Europe/Berlin"}
Recurrence: RRULE:FREQ=DAILY;COUNT=3
RecurringEventId: null
```

Then I expand search criteria (please mind `min` object value) and execute the same query, then I got one less result.

```
DateTime min = new DateTime(System.currentTimeMillis() - 400000000);
DateTime max = new DateTime(System.currentTimeMillis() + 400000000);
```

Then return only

```
Event ID: cq61agdr4sbdnfj7rfbpbk2pro 
Summary: Google Calendar API test event 
Status: confirmed 
Event Start/End: {"dateTime":"2017-05-17T15:24:53.000+02:00","timeZone":"Europe/Berlin"} {"dateTime":"2017-05-17T16:24:53.000+02:00","timeZone":"Europe/Berlin"}
Recurrence: [RRULE:FREQ=DAILY;COUNT=3]
RecurringEventId: null
```

My question is why when I search starting from `current time - 400000000` there is one event less than when searching starting from `current time - 3600000` ?

Comment: What's actually more confusing is why an event with a `cancelled` status being returned with a request that has `showDeleted` as `false`. Would it still show up once you reverted back to the previous request (`min` as `3600000`)?

Comment: Hello @AL. I also think it's weird, but this is mentioned in their API documentation: _showDeleted: Whether to include deleted events (with status equals "cancelled") in the result. Cancelled instances of recurring events (but not the underlying recurring event) will still be included if showDeleted and singleEvents are both False. If showDeleted and singleEvents are both True, only single instances of deleted events (but not the underlying recurring events) are returned. Optional. The default is False._